# What does "no man is an island" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this quote mean?

> ...no man is an island, entire of itself, every man is a piece of the continent..

Comment: Related [Meaning of "no man is an island, entire by itself"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105801/meaning-of-no-man-is-an-island-entire-by-itself)

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

It means that no man, and no woman, can accomplish anything alone and needs other people to be complete, and that individualism can only be viable up to a point.

Comment: @lama You're most perfectly welcome, dude/dudette ...